# OLEDate java implementation

Tags: java, date, coledatetime

I need a good OLEDate java implementation, and [this one](http://www.koders.com/java/fid7032A05F56DE8DB0933CD8497E2A1525C98E1E3E.aspx?s=oledate#L6) does not seem to be working. Is there any known good opensource implementations (like in apache commons)? If not, where do I read about it, so that I write my own implementation?

Comment: Why does the koders.com code not work?  nearest I can tell, it depends on the floating point implementation, which isn't at all portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Old New Thing blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/05/54806.aspx) seems to be a decent treatise on the topic:

*The OLE automation date format is a floating point value, counting days since midnight 30 December 1899. Hours and minutes are represented as fractional days.*

If you have access to Visual Studio and the MFC COleDateTime source, you can reimplement that in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
public static Date getDateFromCOMDate(float comtime) {
    String floatstr = String.valueOf(comtime);
    String [] ss = floatstr.split("\\.");
    long nulltime = -2209183200000L;
    long dayms = 86400000;
    int days = Integer.valueOf(ss[0]);
    float prop = comtime - days;
    long cdayms = Math.round(dayms * prop);
    long time = nulltime + days*dayms + cdayms;
    Date d = new Date(time);
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous implementation is buggy, e.g. wrong dates for 1.0 and -1.25.
The implementation below conforms to OLE date described in MSDN, e.g. here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx

Implementation below does conform to the MSDN documentation.
It converts a BigDecimal value to Joda LocalDateTime.
BigDecimal is better than float and double since it is able to hold a precise value.

```
class COMDateToRegularDateConverter {
    private static final LocalDateTime ZERO_COM_TIME = new LocalDateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0);
    private static final BigDecimal MILLIS_PER_DAY = new BigDecimal(86400000);

    LocalDateTime toLocalDateTime(BigDecimal comTime) {
        BigDecimal daysAfterZero = comTime.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN);
        BigDecimal fraction = comTime.subtract(daysAfterZero).abs(); //fraction always represents the time of that day
        BigDecimal fractionMillisAfterZero = fraction.multiply(MILLIS_PER_DAY).setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);

        return ZERO_COM_TIME.plusDays(daysAfterZero.intValue()).plusMillis(fractionMillisAfterZero.intValue());
    }
}
```