# Java vs c++ types

Tags: java, c++, datetime, types, coledatetime

I've recently had a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599102/oledate-java-implementation) about coledatetime java implementation, and [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51789/chris-kaminski) said, that the problem might lay in type conversions: cpp-float vs java-float (Or maybe cpp-date vs java-date. Not types, but..). Now I have several questions on this:

- Is there a table of comparison for java vs c++ types?
- If type conversions **is** the problem, in my situation (I have a db with OLEDate records, already created with some c++ program. I need to read and write to that db, so that the OLEDate field compatibility remained: my java code reads proper dates, and c++ program is not affected with what the java program wrote to the db.), what would you do:

  - Use COleDateTime to retrieve the date with JNI?
  - Create your own implementation at all costs (using broader types, or anything else)?
- Is there anything, I'm missing here?

Comment: I'd agree with David - it would be nice to know what wasn't working from the koders code. It seems very unlikely it is a difference in the floating types.

Comment: It sometimes breaks c++ code. I do not have access to that code, so I dont't know, what happens there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++ type ranges can and do differ from one implementation (compiler/architecture) to another, so there is no standard Java-C++ type comparisons as there is no standard C++ type sizes.

But in most current architectures C++ doubles are standard IEEE 754 doubles, as it is in Java. So while the code will not be strictly portable to some rare architecture, it will more often than not work in any x86/x86_64 architectures.

There was a question in the comments of the previous answer that you did not address: what is it that does not work in the implementation you have?

Comment: So.. Does this mean, that COleDateTime is platform dependent in c++? I mean, if I compare float, that is returned from COleDateTime on x86 with the one, that I get on my x86_64, they shall be different even if both COleDateTime objects are constructed with exactly same dates?

Comment: float and double are in x86 and x86_64 are the same types. Depending on the concrete operations you are performing and what processor you are running it in, the results might be slightly different due to rounding issues (you should never use direct equality comparisons with floating point data, but that is a different question), but with similar processors (say the same processor running 32 or 64 bit OS) the result should be consistent.